# Нужен ввод двух разных типов данных в одну строку

Tags: python

```
x = str(input())
if x == "int":
    y = str(input())
    z = int(input())
    print(z + 1)

Выводит:
int #Я ввел
a  #Я ввел
1024 #Я ввел
1025
Нужно чтобы выводило:
int a 1024
1025
```

А, также, чтоб писать через пробел без энтера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понимаю для чего это вам нужно, но да ладно, вот решение:

```py
some_value = input() #int a 1024
x, y, z = some_value.split() #split разбивает строку на три состовляющих [int, a, 1024], потом присваиваем переменным x,y,z небходимые значения
print(x) #int
print(y) #a
print(z) #1024

if x == "int":
    print(int(z) + 1) #1025
```